# Is possible to manipulate the value of <input type="file"/> from a signed java app?

Tags: java, javascript, dom, java-web-start

I'm trying to use a client-side [JWS](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) application with the [jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info) [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) plugin.  I'm using a JWS app to do client-side file manipulation which I then want to upload to my web server.  I've limited Java experience, so I wanted to leverage Uploadify for a better user experience while submitting the file.  I know JS has a security restriction which won't allow this, but I figured a signed Java application may not have this issue.

Comment: By JWS DYM [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info)?  What does 'UX' mean?

Comment: @Paul: editing the value of an `<input type="file">`. J.P: why don't you just handle the upload **entirely** by JWS? E.g. with Swing `JFileChooser`. The only communication language between JWS and HTML is also JS. So you're stuck here. There are by the way 3rd party libraries for this such as JumpLoader and JUpload.

Comment: @BalusC: I was looking at JFileChooser but it would be an annoying user interaction to go and select the file that they were just manipulating for submittal back to the server.  I think I can use the HttpClient library to POST the file while using a JS callback for front-end notification.  Though I'm not sure how I'll be able to capture bytes transfered and convert that to a upload percentage.  Thanks for your responses.

Comment: @J.P.: Don't you already have a reference to "file that they were just manipulating?" Can't you use something like [`HttpClient`](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365153/HttpClient-and-FileUpload)?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

The longer answer is you are not allowed to modify or manipulate an HTMLFileInput object by any means. This includes the use of JavaScripts on the same page, and also signed/unsigned Java applications.

This is done for security reasons, and there are no workarounds for this.